# Avoiding use of "who" while maintaining proper syntax

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How do I say the following phrases - typeset in bold - without using "who"? The situation is children on a playground, and attention is given to those on the swings. If I wanted to say something slightly different, the first phrase in bold could be simply stated. "If a child already on the swings were to leave the playground, the fraction of children playing on the swings would be 2/7."

Here is the situation.

There are some children on a playground, and some of them are playing on the swings. If another child were to enter the playground and play on the swings, the fraction of children playing on the swings would be 3/10. If **a child already on the playground who had not been playing on the swings** were to leave the playground, the fraction of children playing on the swings would be 2/7. Compute **the number of children on the playground who are not playing on the swings**.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the pronoun "who"? Is another pronoun acceptable or are you trying to avoid pronouns completely? (And "**in** the playground")

Comment: I would prefer to avoid "question pronouns." (I have always heard "children **on** the playground," "children **on** the school bus," and "children **in** school.")

Comment: Compute the readability of that quote.  It really sucks, "who" aside.

Comment: @Hot Licks I know what it is saying. It was a question on a county-wide math league competition. So, a lot of high school students also knew what it is saying.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Those aren’t interrogative pronouns, but relative pronouns. But _why_ do you want to avoid them? It’s a bit like saying you want to avoid verbs or nouns or adjectives – it may make sense as the point of some specific exercise (which is what we’d then need to know what is in order to comply with it), but it doesn’t make any sense as a goal in itself because it doesn’t exist in natural English.

Comment: Voting to close Q. as "Unclear what you are asking" as every proposal and comment suggested be respondents is rejected by OP as inappropriate for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest:

> There are some children in a playground, and some of them are playing on the swings. If a new child were to enter the playground and play on the swings, the fraction of children playing on the swings would be 3/10. If a child, already on the playground but not playing on the swings, were to leave the playground, the fraction of children playing on the swings would be 2/7. Compute the number of children that are in the playground but not playing on the swings.

Used the preposition "*in* the playground", since it is acceptable and *on* is already used for swings, and no other substitute would work for that phrase.

Comment: The problem must have the same answer as the original problem.

Comment: edited. it does now; forgot last "not"

Comment: There is a subtle difference between Op's version & your suggestion. Op has: "a child already on the playground *who **had not*** been playing on the swings". I read that as meaning "a child that had *not played on the swings **at all*** [during the current session]".  Your version refers to whether the child **is currently** playing on the swings. But, original is also ambiguous because it then asks for the "the number of children ... not **[currently]** playing on the swings."

Comment: @TrevorD  The situation is not ambiguous - but I do understand how there could be confusion. A situation involving n children at a playground is described.m of them are on the swings. If the situation is changed as described in the second sentence, there would be n+1 children on the playground, and m+1 of them would be on the swings. In this case, (m+1)/(n+1)=3/10. If the situation is changed as described in the third sentence, there would be n-1 children on the playground, and m of them would be on the swings. In this case, m/(n-1)=2/7.

Comment: @TrevorD  With these expressions, we can evaluate m and n. The answer will be m - n.

Comment: @Carly In the last sentence, you have "the number of children **that** ...  ."  You're replacing "who" with "that."

Comment: @Carly I am not sure the sentence is grammatically correct with "that" following "children."

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire As I already pointed out, the current wording refers to "**who had not been** playing on the swings" - that is the PAST tense: it says nothing about how many children are **currently** playing on the swings.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Referring to your comments with Carly, "who"" and "that" **are interchangeable** in this particular context.

Comment: @TrevorD The second and third sentences are conditional clauses. They didn't actually happen. I was taught that when using conditional clauses, use the past tense of auxiliary verbs. You will see that I have "If another child **were** to enter the playground" in the second sentence.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire it looks like the past auxiliary but it is a mood - subjunctive/irrealis (not-real). "WERE" is to be used in those cases, yes

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire replacing "who" with "that" in last sentence because the referent is "the number" (that) and not "the children" (who)

Comment: @Carly Thanks for both the affirmation and the explanation. Seeing some of these grammatical terms is helpful. I did not know there were so many grammatical moods. (I mostly use subjunctive and conditional.)

Comment: @Carly I see that you changed "If a child already on the playground who had not been playing on the swings were to leave the playground ... " to "If a child, already on the playground but not playing on the swings, were to leave the playground ... ." What grammatical device did you use?